# Converting png images with transparency to jpg is ruining the image

Tags: image, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am trying to convert any image that a user uploads into the jpg format with a white background. However, I've noticed that when the user uploads a PNG image which contains transparency, ColdFusion is ruining the whole image. It almost looks like there's digital corruption going on.

So the user first provides a URL for where the image is located and `cfhttp` is used to read it in:

```
<cfhttp url="http://pathtoimage/image.png" method="get" useragent="#CGI.http_user_agent#" getasbinary="yes" result="PageResult">
<cfimage name="UserImg" source="#PageResult.FileContent#" />
```

So now `UserImg` is the image that the user wants to upload. Next we do the usual of setting antialiasing on and I also want the background to be white because the image could have a transparent background:

```
<cfset ImageSetAntialiasing(UserImg, "on")>
<cfset ImageSetBackgroundColor(UserImg, "white")>
```

The final stage is to write it to server as a jpg file:

```
<cfimage source="#UserImg#" action="write" destination="pathtoimages/userimage.jpg" overwrite="yes" format="jpg" />
```

The problem is that PNG images with transparency gets completely ruined. What should have a white background and be a clear jpg image ends up all blocky with a black background. Here's an example:

Original image:
[image: original png image]

After jpg conversion:
[image: converted to jpg image]

How do I work around this?

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion are you using? Are you sure it supports this conversion?

Comment: ColdFusion 11. Leigh's answer worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ImageSetBackgroundColor has no effect in that code.  Per the documentation it:

> Sets the background color for the ColdFusion image. **The background
>   color is used for clearing a region**. Setting the background color only
>   affects the subsequent ImageClearRect calls.

Since standard jpeg's do not support transparency, the partially transparent areas are essentially converted to black when the image is saved as a jpeg.

Instead, try pasting the transparent PNG onto a new image with a white background. Then do the conversion on the new image.

```
<!--- use "rgb" to make background opaque --->
<cfset UserImgCopy = ImageNew("", UserImg.Width, UserImg.Height, "rgb", "white")>
<cfset ImagePaste(UserImgCopy, UserImg, 0, 0)>
<cfset ImageWrite(UserImgCopy, "c:\path\userimage.jpg", true)>
```

Comment: Just splendid. Worked exactly how I wanted thank you Leigh :)

Comment: I've had issues with images being to large for ColdFusion to process in-memory (Java heap error). I use GraphicsMagick (free) w/ColdFusion 8-11 and the command line syntax to convert a PNG-to-JPG using a white background is `gm convert -transparent white -extent 0x0 #PNGPathIn# #JPGPathOut#`.

Comment: Yes, CF/java is not always the best tool for image processing given how memory intensive it can be.